# WSO2 - Using get-property() function in Property/Xquery Mediators

Tags: operation, wso2, mediator

Our current service has 7 operations. when writing an outbound xquery "local entry" in wso2, we're trying to retrieve the name of the current operation being executed (how can this be so difficult?).

After reading what i could find in wso2's documentation. it appears as if we need to set up both a Property and an Xquery mediator. supposedly the property mediator would pull the value doing something like get-property('OperationName') and then this would be referenced and passed thru the Xquery mediator.

The other idea was that we needed to define it as a variable in the "Local Registry entry definitions" and than it would be around at all parts of the sequence.

I've tried for 2 days but haven't quite got it.

Please tell me what I'm missing...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following xquery sample[1]? I modified the query mediator to get the operation name as follows.

<variable xmlns:ax21="http://services.samples/xsd" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples" name="code" expression="get-property('OperationName')" type="STRING" />

this worked fine. I could see the getQuote in the response message.

[1] http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.2/docs/samples/advanced_mediation_samples.html#Sample390